# Using an Arduino uno to program a standalone ATmega2560

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, bootloader, atmega

I have successfully programmed standalone ATmega328p using an Arduino uno by adding following lines in the boards.txt file:

```
atmega328bb.name=ATmega328 on a breadboard (8 MHz internal clock)
atmega328bb.upload.protocol=stk500
atmega328bb.upload.maximum_size=30720
atmega328bb.upload.speed=57600
atmega328bb.bootloader.low_fuses=0xE2
atmega328bb.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDA
atmega328bb.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
atmega328bb.bootloader.path=arduino:atmega
atmega328bb.bootloader.file=ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328_pro_8MHz.hex
####atmega328bb.bootloader.file=ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328.hex
atmega328bb.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
atmega328bb.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
atmega328bb.build.mcu=atmega328p
atmega328bb.build.f_cpu=8000000L
atmega328bb.build.core=arduino:arduino
atmega328bb.build.variant=standard
atmega328bb.bootloader.tool=arduino:avrdude
```

The bootloader worked and I was able to run blink example successfully on a standalone ATmega328p.

Now, I am trying to upload a blink example to the standalone ATmega2560. I selected the board as ATmega2560 from the Tools menu (in-built board ATmega2560) and ran the bootloader. I didn't make any changes for the ATmega2560 in the `boards.txt` file) The bootloader worked and the code was uploaded to the ATmega2560 successfully.

However, the problem is that the blink example is not working. The LED on pin 26 on a standalone board turns ON for a very short period then turns OFF for a very short period and then again turns ON for a short period and finally turns OFF for 1 second.  This cycle is repeated.  However, the blink code should turn the LED ON then provides a delay of 1 second and then turns off for a 1 second and this cycle is repeated. The blink code is not working as it should work on my standalone ATmega2560

I tested the same thing using a `TIMER1`. I wrote code to blink the LED after every 0.03 seconds. This works fine in standalone ATmega328p but it doesn't work on a Standalone ATmega2560.

What would be the problem?  Do I need to add some lines for standalone ATmega2560 in the `boards.txt` file?

I connected all VCC pins, GND pins and crystal including the filter capacitor and resistor as shown in the fig.

[image]

After, I connected the reset pin to 5v through a 10k resistor.

After, I did the following:

- Arduino Uno pin 10 to reset pin of standalone ATmega2560
- Arduino Uno pin MISO to pin MISO of standalone ATmega2560
- Arduino Uno pin MOSI to pin MOSI of standalone ATmega2560
- Arduino Uno pin SCK to pin SCK of standalone ATmega2560

Please help!

Comment: Grammar fixes and typos

Comment: This is probably more suited for Electrical Engineering StackExchange: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the Board.txt file, in the ATMEGA2560 section, you have to replace the value of "0xD8" with "0xD9". This is so, because in stand-alone ATMEGA2560 chips, if the BOOTRST fuse is not set, the chip will be correctly programmed, but the programs will never run. So the line could look like this ( we can keep the original line commented ):

## #mega.menu.cpu.atmega2560.bootloader.high_fuses=0xD8

## mega.menu.cpu.atmega2560.bootloader.high_fuses=0xD9

A tutorial here :
https://soc.ninja/documentation/programming-atmega2560-with-arduino-uno-or-mega/

Comment: After doing this. I am not able to upload sketch again via FTDI cable. If I leave 0xD8 then I can upload any number of times but does not run. While with 0xD9 Run fine on every power On but No more sketch uploading.